# Tkinter Buttons: How make sure certain buttons have been pressed before running the main part of your script

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I apologize for the terribly worded question, I just could not figure out a better way to present my problem. I am writing a script that demonstrates the Monty Hall Problem using an interactive GUI. On my first frame I have 3 Buttons labeled "Door A", "Door B" and "Door C." And underneath those 3 buttons I have 2 other buttons labeled "Switch Choice" and "Keep Choice."

The 3 buttons that represent the "Doors" call my method named `initialGuess(self,door)` while the bottom 2 buttons which represent whether or not the user would like to keep or switch his choice call the method `switch_choice(self, val)`. I want to make sure the user chooses a door and whether he wants to switch his choice BEFORE the simulation of the Monty Hall problem. Both buttons run two different methods, How do I write a script that makes sure both methods have been run and that once it has been confirmed the user made both choices it will run the main part of the simulation.

To help with this here are my buttons and corresponding methods for them. (I apologize in advance for all the global variables I plan on creating other methods for them, this is just an blueprint to start off).

```
class MontyHallSim(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = Label(self, text="Monty Hall Problem", font=Large_Font)
        label.place(x=150, y=100, width=500, height=50)

        doorA = Button(self, text="Door A", font=Small_Font,
                       relief=RAISED, height=10, width=50,
                       command=lambda: self.initialGuess("A"))
        doorA.place(x=125, y=200, width=150, height=400)

        doorB = Button(self, text="Door B", font=Small_Font,
                       relief=RAISED, height=10, width=50,
                       command=lambda: self.initialGuess("B"))
        doorB.place(x=325, y=200, width=150, height=400)

        doorC = Button(self, text="Door C", font=Small_Font,
                       relief=RAISED , height=10, width=50,
                       command=lambda: self.initialGuess("C"))
        doorC.place(x=525, y=200, width=150, height=400)

        switch= Button(self, text="Switch Choice",
                       relief=RAISED, height=10, width=50,
                       command=lambda: self.switch_choice("Y"))
        switch.place(x=100, y=600, width=100, height=50)

        no_switch = Button(self, text="Keep Choice",
                           relief=RAISED,  height=10, width=50,
                           command=lambda: self.switch_choice("N"))
        no_switch.place(x=600, y=600, width=100, height=50)

    global doors
    global game
    global prize
    global guess
    global empty_door
    global initial
    global moderator
    global stay
    global switch
    global selection

    selection=None
    moderator="Moderator"
    guess=None
    empty_door="Empty"
    prize="Prize"
    initial="Guess"
    doors=("A", "B", "C")
    game={"A":"Empty","B":"Empty", "C":"Empty"}

    def initialGuess(self,door):
        guess=door
        game[guess]=initial
        tm.showinfo("Monty Hall", "You Chose Door %.2s" %guess)
        return guess

    def switch_choice(self,val):
        switch="Y"
        stay="N"
        if val==switch:
            selection=switch
            tm.showinfo("Monty Hall", "You Chose To Switch Your Guess!")
        else:
            selection=stay
            tm.showinfo("Monty Hall", "You Chose The Original Door")
        return selection

    def run_sim(self):
        iterations=1000
        win_count=0
        lose_count=0
        for _ in range(iterations):
            #Sets the Prize stores Prize "Key" in a value for later use
            placed=random.choice(doors)
            game[placed]=prize
            prize_key=list(game.keys())[list(game.values()).index(prize)]

            #Sets Moderators Choice
            moder=list(game.keys())[list(game.values()).index(empty_door)]
            game[moder]=moderator

            #checks to see if switch is performed
            if selection=="Y":
                new_guess=random.choice(
                    [x for x in doors if x != guess and x!=moderator])
                game[new_guess]=initial
                game[guess]=empty_door
                guess=new_guess
                game[prize_key]=prize
            else:
                pass

            #Checks Game dictionary for "Guess"; If guess is present you
            #lose...
            #If guess is NOT present that means the Prize is in the door that
            #you guessed
            try:
                open_guess = (
                    list(game.keys())[list(game.values()).index(guess)])
                if open_guess in game:
                    lose_count += 1
            except ValueError:
                win_count += 1

        percent_won=float(win_count/iterations*100.)
        percent_lost=float(lose_count/iterations*100)
        tm.showinfo("Percent Won: %.2f" %percent_won)
        tm.showinfo("Percent Lost: %.2f" %percent_lost)
```

Comment: you need some variables with `True/False` to control it.

Comment: You can make all of your globals attributes of the `MontyHallSim` and reference then via `self.attribute_name` in the methods of the class. The same technique would allow you to add additional variables like @furas suggested to keep track of what the user has done and the state of the game simulation. You can then add a new method that does the checks you want to have done and call it before the `run_sim()` method or call it from that method (methods can call other methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable (`tk.DISABLED`) and enable (`tk.NORMAL`) buttons and other widgets. So the `keep choice` button can be disabled until a choice is made. You might want to use `Radiobutton` instead perhaps? And maybe a `messagebox` to check if the player wants to switch or not?

Here is a quick and messy code example, it might give you some ideas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

def reset_choice():
    button_run.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    button_a.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    button_b.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    button_c.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)

def reset_sim():
    global choice
    global switch
    reset_choice()
    choice.set('')
    switch = False

def run_sim():
    global choice
    global switch
    if messagebox.askyesno('Are you sure?', 'You chose {}, do you want to switch?'.format(choice.get())):
        reset_choice()
        switch = True
    else:
        print('You chose door {}'.format(choice.get()))
        if switch:
            print('You switched choice before running')
        print('Running sim...')
        reset_sim()


def select_door():
    button_run.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    button_a.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    button_b.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    button_c.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

choice = tk.StringVar()
switch = False

button_a = ttk.Radiobutton(frame, text="A", variable=choice, value="A", command=select_door)
button_b = ttk.Radiobutton(frame, text="B", variable=choice, value="B", command=select_door)
button_c = ttk.Radiobutton(frame, text="C", variable=choice, value="C", command=select_door)

button_run = ttk.Button(frame, text="Run", command=run_sim, state=tk.DISABLED)

button_a.grid(column=0, row=0)
button_b.grid(column=1, row=0)
button_c.grid(column=2, row=0)
button_run.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The `Run` button isn't enabled before an alternative is chosen, and when you pick a choice you can't switch. When you press `Run` a `messagebox` asks if you want to switch. If yes, the choices are enabled again and a `switch` variable is set to `True`.

When you choose to not switch, it prints what your choice and if you switched it prints a line stating just that. And then it resets the choice and `switch` set to `False` (just so it is back to scratch again).

Comment: Thank you all for the help I was able to figure out a solution from all of your suggestions. I was able to get my program to run the way I wanted to. I am still making adjustments to my coding to simplify it and make it better overall. Again thank you for the help, it really is appreciated!